# JIRA JQL Module and Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, jira, jql

I am trying to write my first JQL function. Therefore I need to access the BrowseContext of the user. How can I access it?

I tried to add it as a constructor using

```
private final BrowseContext ctx;

public MyFunction(BrowseContext ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

}
```

The result is an Exception stating:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.atlassian.jira.project.browse.BrowseContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Any idea what goes wrong or what do I have to change?

Comment: I don't know enough JIRA to help you, but I think people who do know enough are still going to need more context from you. Can you give a complete minimal reproducible code sample? How are you running the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of reading and debugging I found the solutions. I was missing the annotations (Tutorial can be found here: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/search/tutorial-adding-a-jql-function-to-jira)

Important are @Scaned above the class and @ComponentImport above the member varaiable